# SKSpriteNode Changing Scene Lag

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code that runs when the player dies. It basically "resets" the SKScene by transitioning to the same scene over and over again when the player dies.

```
let moveScene = Level1(size: self.size)
let transition = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Up, duration: 0.7)
moveScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
self.scene!.view?.presentScene(moveScene, transition: transition)
```

I am noticing that everytime the player dies, the FPS drop by like 2FPS for each death / level complete. If I purposely die 20 times really quickly, I start to get 25FPS and the game gets really laggy.

Is there another way I can successfully reset the current SKScene to avoid this problem? I am using SKSpriteNodes for my gameplay, not SKShapeNodes :)

Cheers

Comment: You don't get enough information to answer that something concrete. But generally 155 `SKShapeNode` objects can make very weak performance. Apple not recommend to use this class if it can replace to `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: Thanks alex_p. I changed all my SKShapeNode's to SKSpriteNode. This greatly increased the FPS to 60FPS. However, after I reset the SK Scene, my FPS still drops. It has something to do with resetting the SKScene. Any ideas?

I have edited the question above :)

Comment: are you sure your old scene is being dropped?  You could just be adding scene onto scene, and all these scenes could be running without you even knowing it

Comment: FYI,  if you are presenting your new scene inside your old scene this can cause problems,  you should treat new scenes like you would treat view controllers,  that is, create a delegation method where the parent of the scene handles the swapping of scenes,  not children.  So in your case,  the scene should tell the SKView that a new scene is needed, and the SKView should make the change.